# Php how to open bootstrap selectbox options in modal popup not the regular combobox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I have the regular combobox but i dont want to open it like regular i want to open the modal popup when i click on combobox to open and the all `<option>` should me open in that modal popup and i will select options from there.

I donnot know that how to make it with jquery or javascript or using css.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

```
<select name="xyz">
i want to open the below option in modal popup to select from there.
<option>001</option>
<option>002</option>
<option>003</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, if you add some code to the question showing what you have already tried that may help people to get an answer for you quicker. Also show examples of the Bootstrap Modal and the code to trigger it - as people not familiar with Bootstrap will be able to answer your question as well that way. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

You do as you said. You build a modal with your options and have a way to open the modal when you click the field.

All you need is a button a text element and a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" id="option">
<button role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#selectModal">
    Select an Option
</button>
<span id="optionName"></span>
```

The button will trigger the modal. In the modal, you will have your available options clickable and on click update the value of the input and the content of the text element.

```
$(option).on('click', function () {
    $('#option').val($(this).attr('value'));
    $('#optionName').text($(this).text());
    $('#selectModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Full Example https://jsfiddle.net/orcjugj2/4/